# Increasing Values in one Column Using CSV Module and Python

Tags: python, csv

All I would like to do is add .001 to each value that isn't a 0 in one column (say column 7 for example) in my csv file.

So instead of being 35, the value would be changed to 35.001 for example. I need to do this to make my ArcMap script work because if a whole number is the first read, the column is assigned as a short integer when it needs to be read as a float.

As of right now, I have:

```
writer.writerow([f if f.strip() =='0' else f+.001 for f in row])
```

This creates a concatenation error however and does not yet address the specific column I need this to work on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to just mutate the row in place, i.e.

```
if row[7].strip() != '0' and '.' not in row[7]:
    row[7] = row[7] + '.001'
writer.writerow(row)
```

- The concatenation error is caused by trying to add a float to a string, you just have to wrap the extra decimals in quotes
- The extra condition on the if ensures that you don't accidentally end up with a number with 2 decimal points
- It's pretty standard for numbers of the form like 35.0 to be treated as floats even though it's a whole number - check if ArcMap follows this convention, and then you can avoid reducing the accuracy of your numbers by just appending `'.0'`